# Where was Babie, Russia (era 1890's)?

Tags: 19th-century, poland, russia, historical-gazetteer

Where was Babie, Russia?

My grandmother was born in 1890 from that town (now Poland, I believe.) I'm interested in knowing the religious affiliations or majority as there is a question of Jewish heritage. I'd like to know sources where I could find information. Her last name was Gadomska or Godomska with her mother's maiden name being Dziamalek

Comment: Could it be "Babice", rather than "Babie"? There are [several possibilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babice) for "Babice" in Poland and the Czech Republic.

Comment: IT could be. The ONLY document I have is a passenger record on the ship Kaiserin Auguste Victoria  (55/22/1909.) It stated place of residence as: Babie Russia. It easily could have been mis- spelled or miss read. It also lists her name as Leonora Gadowska

Comment: There are at least 7 villages called 'Babye' in Russia and neighbourhood : https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Бабье

Answer (score 3):

Could it be "Babice", rather than "Babie"? There are [several possibilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babice) for "Babice" in Poland and the Czech Republic.

---

I found an online copy of the passenger list from the Kaiserin Auguste Victoria's arrival in New York in May 1909. Leonora's record is shown here:

[image: left page]

[image: right page]

The handwriting isn't the best that I've ever seen!

However, it does include an address in Syracuse, which may help you find her in the 1910 US census or New York naturalisation records. I doubt the census will have the town in Poland, but a naturalisation document might.

The entry also has the name of a friend / relative in Poland which might help you with your search.

---

I also did a quick search on FamilySearch and found Leonora listed in the 1920 and 1930 censuses, but I'm guessing you already have those records.